# How do I make Mathematica understand roots of unity?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

Try the following:

```
z = Exp[2 \[Pi] I / 5]

Z = { { z, 1 }, { 0, 1/z } }

Simplify[MatrixPower[Z, 5]] //MatrixForm
```

Of course, this should return a 2 x 2 identity matrix. Instead, we get:

```
{{1, 1 - (-1)^(1/5) + (-1)^(2/5) - (-1)^(3/5) + (-1)^(4/5)}, {0, 1}}
```

That is, *Mathematica* doesn't seem to understand that summing these roots of unity gives zero.  Is there some way to make it realize this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `FullSimplify`:

```
m = {{1, (1 - (-1)^(1/5) + (-1)^(2/5) - (-1)^(3/5) + (-1)^(4/5)) b}, {0, 1}};

m // FullSimplify
```

> `{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}`

Alternatively, for this very specific situation you can use the `ExpToTrig` function which will convert expressions of the form $(-1)^\alpha$ to $\cos (\pi  \alpha )+i \sin (\pi  \alpha )$.  When written in this form, the terms cancel trivially, thus the simplification is done automatically.  `ExpToTrig` will be a bit faster, in case this matters in your application or you have huge expressions on which `FullSimplify` is very slow.

```
ExpToTrig[m]
```

> `{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}`

Comment: `ComplexExpand` also works here.

Answer (score 6):

As István says, `FullSimplify[MatrixPower[Z, 5]]`, is the usual way to do things when `Simplify[]` just isn't cutting it. `ExpToTrig[]`/`ComplexExpand[]` are very handy in this specific application as well, but if you've already done the work with `Simplify[]` as with the OP, the only further push needed can be done via `RootReduce[]`:

```
Simplify[MatrixPower[Z, 5]]
{{1, 1 - (-1)^(1/5) + (-1)^(2/5) - (-1)^(3/5) + (-1)^(4/5)}, {0, 1}}

RootReduce[%]
{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}
```